# How do i close the form after the user picks a drive?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderSelect("Please select:");
    }

    public static string FolderSelect(string txtPrompt)
    {
        // Now, we want to use the path information to population
        // our folder selection initial location
        string initialCheckoutPathDir = ("C:\\"); 
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo info =
            new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(initialCheckoutPathDir);

        FolderBrowserDialog FolderSelect = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderSelect.SelectedPath = info.FullName;
        FolderSelect.Description = txtPrompt;
        FolderSelect.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        if (FolderSelect.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string retPath = FolderSelect.SelectedPath;

            if (retPath == null)
                retPath = "";

            DriveRecursion(retPath);
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

So i have a WindowsForm with a button.  The user presses the button, and the FolderBrowserDialog appears.  Once the user selects a drive, i want the form (with the button) to close as well.

I haven't been having any luck.  Any ideas?  Syntax would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your code will even compile as it is listed here.  You do not return a value in all cases of the code.  In the if(FolderSelect....) you probably intended to have return DriveRecursion(retPath).  Also, in the button click, you are not doing anything with the return value.  

The simple answer to your question though is to put in a this.Close() in the button click after the FolderSelect function is called. And possibly to check the return value from the function if that is something you need to do.

Comment: Hard to see why you need a form at all.  Just use the dialog directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `FolderSelect` returns `DialogResult.OK`, you need to call `this.close`.  So like this:

```
 public string FolderSelect(string txtPrompt)
    {
        //Value to be returned
        string result = string.empty;

        //Now, we want to use the path information to population our folder selection initial location
        string initialCheckoutPathDir = (@"C:\"); 
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(initialCheckoutPathDir);
        FolderBrowserDialog FolderSelect = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderSelect.SelectedPath = info.FullName;
        FolderSelect.Description = txtPrompt;
        FolderSelect.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        if (FolderSelect.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string retPath = FolderSelect.SelectedPath;
            if (retPath == null)
            {
                retPath = "";
            }
            DriveRecursion(retPath);

            result = retPath;
            //Close this form.
            this.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Edit:**
For some reason your `FolderSelect` method is static.  You should remove the static so it has a reference to the form.

Comment: Might have been static if they are using ReSharper.  It will suggest making any method static if it doesn't reference the containing class.

Comment: thank you!  also--i'm new at this.  but i'm getting an error with FolderSelect -- "not all code paths return a value".  I'm assuming this is b/c instead of return retPath, i'm calling another function.  How do i get this error to go away?

Comment: I have done a quick and dirty update to the code so it always has a return path.  You should evaluate it your self as well.

Comment: hmm..for some reason the form still doesn't close.  i debugged it and it seems that while DriveRecursion(retPath) is hit, result = retPath; and this.close(); never get read by the app.

Comment: If you step through it, is it leaving the `DriveRecursion` method without any exceptions and getting to the `this.close()` line?  Are you calling this method from the correct form?

Comment: as i step through it, it does hit into the DriveRecursion method.  However the this.close() is never reached in the code.

Comment: Then you have something in that method that is an endless loop.  To test that this solution works you can move the form.close() above the DriveRecursion() method.  Then you can start on the problem of the endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call [Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx).
Additionally you *can* open your Form by using [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) instead of just *Show()* and set a [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) before closing it:

```
DialogResult = FolderSelect.ShowDialog();
Close();
```

*EDIT:*
And your *FolderSelect* method should be probably *void*. Better save the result of your *FolderSelect* dialog to a property.

Answer (score 0):

Since FolderSelect is static, you won't have access to the form variables.  So, you have two choices.

A) Make FolderSelect an instance method.  Then you can just do this.Close()  Mind you, the this is not necessary, I'm just putting it there for clarity.

B) Return a boolean from FolderSelect, and if it's true, inside the button click event, call this.Close()

Answer (score 0):

After FolderSelect, put this.Close();